# Base64 Svg to UIImage return nil

Tags: swift, svg, uiimage

I'm trying to convert `Base64 Svg to UIImage`, but I get `nil`.

Everything is OK on this site https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

I try different frameworks on native methods, but all to no avail
I use:

1. ```
   let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: base64Str, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
   polygonImage.image = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)!
   ```

````
2) ```
   if let url = URL(string: base64StrUrl) {
      if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
         polygonImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
      }
   }
````

3. ```
   let anSVGImage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: data)
   self.polygonImage.image = anSVGImage
   ```

Problematic base64:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

Comment: Remove `data:image/svg+xml;base64,` from the String and `SVGKImage` won't be nil, but it doesn't render, I don't know why. Modify maybe the svg, there might be a thing it doesn't parse correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not a valid base64 string.
The link you have given has used some image processing techniques to generate the image, but in swift you have to provide a valid base64 string and if you download the image from the same website then you cannot open that image.

you can validate your base64 string on https://base64.guru/tools/validator

if you want to convert this base64 to image

1. paste your base64 string in [this website](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image) and download .svg file (because you can't get a image file from base64 directly)
2. convert your .svg file .png or .jpg with https://svgtopng.com
3. convert .png or .jpg file to base64 string with https://www.base64encoder.io/image-to-base64-converter/

then use that base64 string you will definitely get image.